# How do I get time range from month beginning till today using arrow?

Tags: python, date

I use `arrow.Arrow.span_range` to get date ranges, how do I get a range for example from 2021-06-01 to 2021-06-17(today)?

Comment: Do you want a single tuple representing the 17-day period, rather than a list of tuples corresponding to each of the 17 days?

Comment: @chepner yes. I need to make a statistics for the past year from July 2020 till today. Previous months are from 1 to 30/31 day and the current must start from 1 day until current date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `span`, but with a count of 17.

```
>>> arrow.Arrow.strptime("2021-06-01", "%Y-%m-%d").span('days', count=17)
(<Arrow [2021-06-01T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2021-06-17T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>)
```